# Can I use the Tango SDK on the Unity Windows Store platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, tango

Can I use the Tango SDK on the Unity Windows Store platform?

What if I can use it?

When I tested, I could not build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's Tango only works with 2 devices which are the [Lenovo Phab series](https://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/smart-devices/-lenovo-smartphones/phab-series/c/phab-series) and the [ASUS Zenphone AR](https://www.asus.com/us/Phone/ZenFone-AR-ZS571KL/). Which are both android devices. Therefor the Tango SDK shouldn't work for an UWP app

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If the answer helped you please consider marking it as the correct answer

Comment: I was not familiar with the stack overflow UI and did not know about it.
Is it right?